# Scaling the random variables $x$ and $y$ in $P(x > y)$ by some positive parameter

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $x$ and $y$ be two independent random variables and assume that both are
exponentially distributed,
\begin{align*}
x  & \sim\exp\left(  \lambda\right)  \\
y  & \sim\exp\left(  \mu\right)
\end{align*}
then we have that
$$
\Pr\left(  x<y\right)  =\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}.
$$
Suppose I need to know the probability of the scaled random variables
$\Pr\left(  x^{\alpha}<y^{\alpha}\right)  $ for $\alpha>0$. Is it true that
$$
\Pr\left(  x<y\right)  =\Pr\left(  x^{\alpha}<y^{\alpha}\right)  ?
$$
If yes, how can I show that? Does this hold for other distributions as well?

Comment: Since both are non-negative random variables, x<y <=> x^a < y^a. It may not hold if x,y can take negative values.

Comment: $X^a$ and $Y^a$ are not _scaled_ versions of $X$ and $Y$. _Scaled_ versions are $aX$ and $aY$.

Comment: This isn't a question about distributions: it's about *events*.  That's what the notations like "$x\lt y$" and "$x^\alpha\lt y^\alpha$" are referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing $x$, $y$ positive:

$$ \Pr\left(  x^{\alpha}<y^{\alpha}\right) \\ = \Pr\left(  \ln (x^{\alpha})<\ln(y^{\alpha})\right) \\ = \Pr\left(  \alpha \ln (x)<\alpha\ln(y)\right) \\ = \Pr\left( \ln (x)< \ln(y)\right) \\ = \Pr\left( x< y\right)$$